# How to draw nodes and arcs across centered text

Tags: trees

I have been trying to draw something for a while now and can't seem to find a way to do it the way I want to have it. I wanna draw something similar to this:

```
(1)               ACGT
                   |
               ----------
               |        |
(2)          ACGT      ACGT
                        |
                    -----------
                    |         |
(3)      ACGT      ACGT      ACGT
                    |
              ------------
              |          |
(4)  ACGT    ACGT       ACGT       ACGT
```

Ideally, each line would be CENTERED. I'd very much appreciate a solution that does not require ANY absolute positioning. I have tried various packages, like qtree and tikz, but I can't seem to get what I want :). The thing I am missing is how to center TikZ nodes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Jesus I just saw that it is not aligned at all like a wanted. Don't know if that will make any sense now...

Comment: All right, first line is just ACGT, second line is ACGTACGT with edge between the first ACGT group and the one on the first line, and the same for the second group with the one on the first line. Then comes the third line: ACGTACGTACGT. The last two groups are children of the second line's last one. And then the same for the last line. What matters is that they are each on a seperate line and that they are centered :). Thank you.

Comment: at ($(x0,y)!.5!(x1,y)$) will place a node midway between (x0,y) and (x1,y).  You'll need to load the calc tikzlibrary.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your quick answer! Let's say now I have three nodes:
\node (root) at( 0,0 ) {ACGT};
\node( lvl2 ) [ below = of root ] {ACGTACGT};
\node( lvl3 ) [ below = of lvl2 ] {ACGTACGTACGTACGT};

I'd like to use what you just gave me to draw arcs from root.south to 1/3 of lvl2 and 2/3 of lvl2. Then draw arcs from lvl2.south to 1/3 of lvl3 and 2/3 of lvl3.

I am not familiar with this notation, could you explain quickly how the ! operator work? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: \coordinate (test1) at (lvl2.north west);
    \coordinate (test2) at (lvl2.north east);
    \coordinate (test3) at ( $(test1) + 1/3*(test2)$ );
    \coordinate (test4) at ( $(test1)!0.33!(test2)$ );
Last line does not compile for a reason that is unknown to me.

Comment: Did you load the calc library?

Comment: The problem with arcs is that they are defined using angles and a radius (plus a starting coordinate).  To draw an arc (or locate a midpoint) given the endpoints will require a lot of calculations.

Comment: @John HI john, thanks again. Yeah I loaded the calc library. It seems like there is an issue that they have fixed in their most recent CVS version: I don't seem to be the only one affected.
Anyways, I was able to work around the parser issue by defining multiple temp vars instead of doing the calculation on one line.
I said an arc but I meant an edge :).

Answer (score 3):

A TikZ tree solution:

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    edge from parent fork down,
    level/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
  }
  \node{ACGT}
    child{node{ACGT}
      child{node{ACGT} edge from parent[draw=none]
        child{node{ACGT} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        child[missing]
      }
      child[missing]
    }
    child{node{ACGT}
      child{node{ACGT}
        child{node{ACGT}}
        child{node{ACGT}}
      }
      child{node{ACGT}
        child[missing]
        child{node{ACGT} edge from parent[draw=none]}
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It turn out there is more than one kind of arc.  One is implemented by "to[out=angle,in=angle,relative]".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative]%controls to-arc
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\draw (A) to coordinate[pos=0,5](C) (B);%places C midway berween A & B on arc
\fill (C) circle (2pt);
\node[above] at (C) {midway};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arc]

If you are opposed to using absolute coordinates, this should get you started.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate(hgap) at (1,0);% horizontal spacing
\coordinate(vgap) at (0,1.5);% vertical spacing
\path
 node(r4label){(4)}
 (r4label.east) +(hgap) node(r4c1){ACGT}
 (r4c1.east) +(hgap) node(r4c2){ACGT}
 (r4c2.east) +(hgap) node(r4c3){ACGT}
 (r4c3.east) +(hgap) node(r4c4){ACGT}
 (r4label) +(vgap) node{(3)}
 ($(r4c1)!0.5!(r4c2)$) +(vgap) node(r3c1){ACGT};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actually, I like the other (trees) solution better.  If you still want arcs, you can use:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={draw=black},
 edge from parent/.style={draw=none}]

\node(top) {root}
child {node(left) {left}}
child {node(right) {right}};
\draw 
 (top.south) to[out=0,in=90] (right.north)
 (top.south) to[out=180,in=90] (left.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree arc]

Comment: Forgot to `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in second MWE `:)`

Comment: Or at least I forgot to copy it.